# Trace of a linear operator in Dirac notation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, operators, definition, linear-algebra, trace

I've been banging my head against a wall trying to find a proof for:

$$Tr() = ∑_⟨||⟩.$$

This is supposedly fundamental knowledge. Can anyone help with the proof or direct me to a resource that has it?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trace_(linear_algebra)#Definition

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trace of an operator $X$ is *defined* as the sum of its diagonal components. That is, $$Tr(X)=\sum_j \langle j|X|j\rangle = \langle 1|X|1\rangle + \langle 2|X|2\rangle + \langle 3|X|3\rangle \ldots $$

Not sure what you mean by a *proof* since as stated above, this is strictly a definition and requires no proof.